# Titanium studio require() javascript module

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium Studio and I was trying to follow the tutorial from appcelerator

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium-section-29004791_CommonJSModulesinTitanium-AntipatternsandUnsupportedBehavior

However, when I create the Person.js (in app/controller folder) and try to use it in my index.js file by

```
var Person = require("Person");
var don = new Person('Don','Thorp');
var donsName = don.fullName(); // "Don Thorp"
```

I encountered the error that the fullNmae() was not defined (it is defined in Person.js).

Did any people have the similar problem? Please help me out,thanks!

The Person.js code is

```
 function Person(firstName,lastName) {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
     return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
    };
    module.exports = Person;
```

The error message is :

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [196,196] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,196] - In alloy/controllers/index.js:1,69
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,196] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'fullName'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,196] - Source: xtend(s,s.__views);var l=require("Person"),c=new l("Don","Thorp");c.fullName()
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/index.js:1: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'fullName'
```

Comment: You should be able to debug this in developer tools.

Comment: Could you please share the error logs and your Person.js code.

Comment: Could you include the code for Person perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it looks like the external .js file has to locate at the folder within assets/ folder (not directly under assets/, it doesn't work, I don't under stand why thogh...). Thanks. 
It might be useful to others who encounter the similar problem.

Comment: Now I have another question: how can I tell the IDE to find the other dependencies? As I have a SDK, where some .js files require() other .js files.